# is there any use for /selinux folder, when I don't use selinux?

Tags: debian, filesystems, selinux

I'm using Debian Wheezy, and by default a folder `/selinux` exists on my filesystem, even though I'm not (knowingly) using any SELinux infrastructure. I know that SELinux is intertwined with some standard packages, for example `ls` is linked with `libselinux.so.1`.

Nevertheless, can I delete the folder `/selinux` on my disk?

I know, it does not take up any space, but still it bothers me to have it around when I don't need/use it.

Can I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this, the directory is owned by `libselinux1` and some packages depend on it. You should not remove files or directories provided by the package manager.

#### Proven on my Debian system (7.6)

To find out, which package owns a path on your system, use

```
$ dpkg -S /selinux/
libselinux1:amd64: /selinux

$ sudo apt-get remove libselinux1
.....
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-21+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.14.2-21+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

That being said, of course this is an oddity of the package `libselinux1`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 sestatus
```

if `permissive` or `active`, you sould have file on it (on /selinux dir). 
if `disabled` diectory shouldn't be there.

disabling is done bu editing `/etc/selinux/config` setting

```
 SELINUX=disabled
```

and reboot.

Comment: I don't have `sestatus` and `/etc/selinux/config` does not even exist.